# Placing Anchored Images on top of table background for email template

Tags: html, css, html-email, mailchimp

I have the following code for a background Image on a table, which has some image links on top of it as well as a logo. I am using a mailchimp account and I would like to make the background editable. it is not possible to make background images editable.

So I am wondering about alternative solutions to have the social links and logo on top of a image while still allowing a image underneath to be editable, so background image **without** a background property in a table, that is compatible in most email clients, that allows for editing in Mailchimp.

```
<table mc:edit="backgroundImage" class="backgroundHeader" background="http://104.131.7.150/public/vancouverSunrise.jpg" border="0" cellpadding="0" height="400" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
            <div align="right" style="padding: 40px 15px 0px 15px;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="30">
                    <!-- LOGO/PREHEADER TEXT -->
                    <tr align="right">
                        <td><a mc:edit="linkedin" href="*|CUSTOM_URL|*"><img src="linkedin.png" width="46.6" height="44" /></a></td>
                        <td><a mc:edit="facebook" href="*|CUSTOM_URL|*"><img src="facebook.png" width="46.6" height="44" /></a></td>
                        <td><a mc:edit="twitter" href="*|CUSTOM_URL|*"><img src="twitter.png" width="46.6" height="44" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
            <div align="center" style="padding: 10px 15px 0px 15px;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="30" class="wrapper">
                    <!-- LOGO/PREHEADER TEXT -->
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td><a href="#"><img src="image.png" width="244" height="126.6" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: using background images is always a bad idea in html-email, use <img> tags instead

Comment: I understand what your saying. But how would I place the other imgs above the main IMG. in a table layout, since alot of email clients wont accept absolute position. or negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `z-index` either so hacking an `img` on top of another is impossible.

You need to have a set up based around the code from http://backgrounds.cm/ and have your `mc:edit` attributes get to the filename in both the background attribute **of the TD** (not the table, table backgrounds don't work in most clients) and the VML script from the generated code. You also need to update the `height` and `width` attributes on the TD and VML.

Comment: P.S. your image pointing to an IP address won't work in Outlook.com (hotmail). and probably a few other clients, haven't tested this thoroughly.

Comment: Thats what I was doing before, just didn't put the mc:edit in the right spot. Jeez. Ok I will go test this and choose this answer ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: Actually Im not quite sure what you mean, get the mc:edit to the filename. Could you give me a example.

Comment: Ah sorry, I don't actually have experience with the MailChimp templating system, but that's essentially what you need to do in order to get a background image working cross-client in an HTML email. Meaning - You need MailChimp to insert the image src in the background="" attribute as well as in the VML code for Outlook.